# Iterate through arrays inside a .replace()

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I need to replace all letters from a string to other signs (stored in an array).

```
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  output.value = input.value.replace(letters[i], signs[i]); //this should be global
}
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var signs = ['.', ':', '-'];

function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    output.value = input.value.replace(letters[i], signs[i]); //this should be global
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="run();">
<input type="text" id="output">
```

If the input says "abc" the output should say ".:-"

Comment: Are two arrays `letters` and `signs` intersect? **i.e.** Could they have common characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the new updated value after the replacing step, what you need to do is store the new value and after replacing the whole set of chars, then set the new value to `output.value`.

An important detail here is that you need to replace all chars which match with a specific letter, to accomplish that you can build a Regexp and use the flag global `g`.

```
new RegExp(letters[i], 'g');
                        ^
                        |
                        +---- This is the flag!
```

Another thing I recommend is to embrace the function `addEventListener` to bind an event to elements.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var signs = ['.', ':', '-'];

function run() {
  var currentInput = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    var rg = new RegExp(letters[i], 'g');
    currentInput = currentInput.replace(rg, signs[i]);
  }
  output.value = currentInput;
}

input.addEventListener('input', run);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="text" id="output">
```

Comment: ;) hah, you always have the eagle eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn you letters  and signs into a lookup table like:

```
{a: ',', b:':' // etc..}
```

so you don't need to search through the letters with each keyup. You can do this once at the beginning, or just use the format to begin with. The you can just `map()` it to a new value

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var signs = ['.', ':', '-'];

let signMap = letters.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  a[c] = signs[i]
  return a
}, {})

function run() {
  output.value = [...input.value].map((i) => signMap[i]).join('')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="run();">
<input type="text" id="output">
```

Another alternative if your letters are always going to be in order is to use the character codes for the lookup in signs. You can also use replace with a generic regex and pass the letter to the function. Then you can avoid the loop altogether. This will ignore input not in the signs, but you could easily just include the original letter if it's not in the signs array.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var signs = ['.', ':', '-'];
let offset = 'a'.charCodeAt(0)

function run() {
  output.value = input.value.replace(/./g, s => signs[s.charCodeAt(0) - offset] || '' )
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="run();">
<input type="text" id="output">
```

Comment: I think you missed a crucial detail. OP wants to replace letters in `input.value`, not `letters` array itself.

Comment: Using map is the typical answer for this kind of replacement +1

Answer (score 1):

**My opinion:**

1. I prefer to create one Object to store all mappings, like what `signMap` does.
2. create one regex like `(a|b|c|ef)` (so you don't need to loop each character for input string, then even it can support multiple letters).  **PS**: assuming the elements in Array=`letters` are not special letters, if yes, you need to adjust Regex Expression for your real case.
3. then uses `String.replace(regex, (replacement)=>{return 'what you need'})`

**like below simple demo:**

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var letters = ['a','b','c', 'ef'];
var signs = ['.',':','-', '@'];

let regex = new RegExp('('+letters.join('|') + ')', 'g') //assume the elements in Array=letters doesn't have special characters.
let signMap = letters.reduce((pre, cur, curIndex) => {
  pre[cur] = signs[curIndex]
  return pre
}, {})

function run() {
  output.value = input.value.replace(regex, (item)=> {
    return signMap[item]
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="run();">
<input type="text" id="output">
```

Comment: I like the Regexp building step, a better approach is get that step out of the function `run`.

Comment: RegExp don’t need pipe inside square brackets. It is either pipe or the brackets